# Magento2 Admin panel Buttons not Work

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml

[image: n]

Hi, I've deployed my Magento store (v2.1.9) and logged into the back end admin panel successfully. However none of the buttons are working, and I'm getting these two errors in my console. Does anyone have any idea the potential cause and/or fix? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that javascript is merged?

Answer (score 1):

Need to clear re generated files

```
rm -rf var/cache/ generated/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and then change following file

> app/etc/di.xml

find the line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and Replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

try clearing cache from command line

> php bin/magento cache:flush

or if still not working then deploy static content it will work for sure